# Why does input.next() work for searching an ArrayList, but .nextLine() does not?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have a simple search method to compare a user's input String with a String in an ArrayList. When I used input.nextLine(), it did not find the String, however, when I used input.next(), it worked. Could someone explain why this error occurs?

The searchPlants method is where the problem was occurring.

The Driver:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Driver {

public String ID = new String();
public String name = new String();
public String color = new String();
public String smell = new String();
public String hasThorns = new String();
public String isPoisonous = new String();
public String isMedicine = new String();
public String isEdible = new String();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {new Driver();}

public Driver() {

    ArrayList<Plant> plantPack = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the PlantPack Application.");
    System.out.println("Please select a number from the options below.");
    System.out.println("");

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("1: Add a plant to the pack.");
        System.out.println("2: Remove a plant from the pack.");
        System.out.println("3: Search for a specific plant.");
        System.out.println("4: Display your plant pack.");
        System.out.println("5: Filter the plant pack by incomplete name.");
        System.out.println("0: Exit the plant pack interface.");

        // Get the user input
        int userChoice = input.nextInt();

        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                typeSwitch(plantPack);
                break;
            case 2:
                removePlant(plantPack);
                break;
            case 3:
                searchPlants(plantPack);
                break;
            case 4:
                displayPlants(plantPack);
                break;
            case 5:
                filterPlants(plantPack);
                break;
            case 0:
                exitInterface();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. \nPlease choose between 1-5, or 0: ");
                break;
        }
    }
}
public void typeSwitch(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {

    System.out.println("Please enter what type of plant you are adding: ");
    System.out.println("1: Flower");
    System.out.println("2: Fungus");
    System.out.println("3: Weed");

    int type = input.nextInt();

    if (type >= 1 && type <= 3) {

        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                addFlower(plantPack);
                break;
            case 2:
                addFungus(plantPack);
                break;
            case 3:
                addWeed(plantPack);
                break;
            }
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Please choose between 1-3: ");
        typeSwitch(plantPack);
    }
}
private void addFlower(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {

    Flower newFlower = new Flower(ID, name, color, smell, hasThorns, isEdible, isPoisonous, isMedicine);

    if(plantPack.size() < 25)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a unique ID number for the flower you wish to add (E.g. F1, F2, etc): ");
        newFlower.setID(input.next().trim());
        input.nextLine();                     //Scanner was eating first input for some reason. Had to fire a blank nextLine() to allow input for every entry, as seen in each subsequent method.
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the flower you wish to add: ");
        newFlower.setName(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Enter the color of the flower you wish to add: ");
        newFlower.setColor(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Does the flower have a scent? Yes or No: ");
        newFlower.setSmell(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Does the flower have thorns? Yes or No: ");
        newFlower.setThorns(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Flower successfully added.\n ");

        plantPack.add(newFlower);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You may only hold 25 items in your PlantPack. Please remove an item before adding another.\n");
    }
}
private void addFungus(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {
    Fungus newFungus = new Fungus(ID, name, color, smell, hasThorns, isEdible, isPoisonous, isMedicine);//(ID, name, color, isPoisonous);

    if(plantPack.size() < 25)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a unique ID number for the Fungus you wish to add (E.g. Fn1, Fn2, etc): ");
        newFungus.setID(input.next().trim());
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the Fungus you wish to add: ");
        newFungus.setName(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Enter the color of the Fungus you wish to add: ");
        newFungus.setColor(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Is this particular Fungus poisonous? Yes or No: ");
        newFungus.setIsPoisonous(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Fungus successfully added.\n");

        plantPack.add(newFungus);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You may only hold 25 items in your plant pack. Please remove one before adding another.");
    }
}
private void addWeed(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {
    Weed newWeed = new Weed(ID, name, color, smell, hasThorns, isEdible, isPoisonous, isMedicine);  //(ID, name, color, isEdible, isPoisonous);

    if(plantPack.size() < 25)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a unique ID number for the Weed you wish to add (E.g. W1, W2, etc): ");
        newWeed.setID(input.next().trim());
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the Weed you wish to add: ");
        newWeed.setName(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Enter the color of the Weed you wish to add: ");
        newWeed.setColor(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Is this particular Weed edible? Yes or No: ");
        newWeed.setIsEdible(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Is this particular Weed medicinal? Yes or No: ");
        newWeed.setIsMedicine(input.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Weed successfully added.\n");

        plantPack.add(newWeed);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You may only hold 25 items in your plant pack. Please remove one before adding another.");
    }
}
private void removePlant(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {

    System.out.println("Which type of Plant do you wish to remove?");
    System.out.println("1: Flower");
    System.out.println("2: Fungus");
    System.out.println("3: Weed");

    int type = input.nextInt();
    switch (type) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the Flower you want to remove: ");
            String deleteFlowerID = input.next().trim();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the Flower you wish to remove: ");
            String deleteName = input.nextLine().trim();

            boolean found = false;

            Iterator<Plant> itr = plantPack.iterator();   //a basic for loop and .equals() would not work, and I don't understand why. I had to go with an Iterator.
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Plant flowers = itr.next();
                if(flowers.getID().equals(deleteFlowerID) && flowers.getName().equals(deleteName)) {
                    itr.remove();

                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
            {
                System.out.println("That Flower was successfully removed from your inventory.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("That Flower was not found in your inventory.");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the Fungus you want to remove: ");
            String deleteFungusID = input.next().trim();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the Fungus you wish to remove: ");
            String deleteFungusName = input.nextLine().trim();

            boolean foundFungus = false;

            Iterator<Plant> fungusItr = plantPack.iterator();
            while(fungusItr.hasNext()) {
                Plant fungi = fungusItr.next();
                if(fungi.getID().equals(deleteFungusID) && fungi.getName().equals(deleteFungusName)) {
                    fungusItr.remove();

                    foundFungus = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundFungus)
            {
                System.out.println("That Fungus was successfully removed from your inventory.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("That Fungus was not found in your inventory.");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the Weed you want to remove: ");
            String deleteWeedID = input.next().trim();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the Weed you wish to remove: ");
            String deleteWeedName = input.nextLine().trim();

            boolean foundWeed = false;

            Iterator<Plant> weedItr = plantPack.iterator();
            while(weedItr.hasNext()) {
                Plant weeds = weedItr.next();
                if(weeds.getID().equals(deleteWeedID) && weeds.getName().equals(deleteWeedName)) {
                    weedItr.remove();
                    foundWeed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundWeed)
            {
                System.out.println("That Weed was successfully removed from your inventory.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("That Weed was not found in your inventory.");
            }
            break;
    }
}
private void searchPlants(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {

    System.out.println("Please enter the ID of the plant you're searching for: ");
    String searchID = input.next().trim();
    input.nextLine();
    boolean match = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < plantPack.size(); i++) {
        if(plantPack.get(i).getID().equals(searchID))
        {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        System.out.println("Found that one in your PlantPack!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, did not find that one.");
    }
}
private void displayPlants(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {

    for(Plant plants : plantPack) {
        System.out.println(plants);
    }
}
private void filterPlants(ArrayList<Plant> plantPack) {

}
private void exitInterface() {
    System.out.println("Are you sure you want to exit the PlantPack Application? Y or N: ");
    while(true) {
        String answer = input.next();
        if(!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && !"N".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter Y or N (not case-sensitive): ");
        }
        if("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the PlantPack Application. See ya later!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Plant class:

```
    public class Plant {

public String ID;
public String name;
public String color;
public String smell;
public String hasThorns;
public String isEdible;
public String isPoisonous;
public String isMedicine;

public Plant(String ID, String name, String color, String smell, String hasThorns, String isEdible, String isPoisonous, String isMedicine) {

    this.ID = ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.smell = smell;
    this.hasThorns = hasThorns;
    this.isEdible = isEdible;
    this.isPoisonous = isPoisonous;
    this.isMedicine = isMedicine;
}

public void setColor(String color) {this.color = color;}
public void setID(String ID) {this.ID = ID;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public String getID() {return ID;}
public String getName() {return name;}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + this.ID + ", Name: " + this.name + ", Color " + this.color;
}

}
```

And the Flower class:

```
    public class Flower extends Plant {

public Flower(String ID, String name, String color, String smell, String  hasThorns, String isEdible, String isPoisonous, String isMedicine) {

    super(ID, name, color, smell, hasThorns, isEdible, isPoisonous, isMedicine);

   }
    public void setSmell(String smell) {this.smell = smell;}
    public void setThorns(String hasThorns) {
    this.hasThorns = hasThorns;
}
public String getSmell() {
    return smell;
}
public String getHasThorns() {
    return hasThorns;
}
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + ", Scent? " + this.smell + ", Thorns? " + this.hasThorns;
}
}
```

This is the output when using input.nextLine():

```
    Welcome to the PlantPack Application.
    Please select a number from the options below.

    1: Add a plant to the pack.
    2: Remove a plant from the pack.
    3: Search for a specific plant.
    4: Display your plant pack.
    5: Filter the plant pack by incomplete name.
    0: Exit the plant pack interface.
    1
    Please enter what type of plant you are adding: 
    1: Flower
    2: Fungus
    3: Weed
    1
    Enter a unique ID number for the flower you wish to add (E.g. F1, F2, etc): 
    F1
    Enter the name of the flower you wish to add: 
    rose
    Enter the color of the flower you wish to add: 
    red
    Does the flower have a scent? Yes or No: 
    yes
    Does the flower have thorns? Yes or No: 
    yes
    Flower successfully added.

    1: Add a plant to the pack.
    2: Remove a plant from the pack.
    3: Search for a specific plant.
    4: Display your plant pack.
    5: Filter the plant pack by incomplete name.
    0: Exit the plant pack interface.
    4
    ID: F1, Name: rose, Color red, Scent? yes, Thorns? yes
    1: Add a plant to the pack.
    2: Remove a plant from the pack.
    3: Search for a specific plant.
    4: Display your plant pack.
    5: Filter the plant pack by incomplete name.
    0: Exit the plant pack interface.
    3
    Please enter the ID of the plant you're searching for: 
    F1
    Sorry, did not find that one.
```

Now, the same thing, but with input.next() instead:

```
    Please enter the ID of the plant you're searching for: 
    F1
    Found that one in your PlantPack!
```

Comment: What input did you enter? Did it contain multiple words?

Comment: Rather than giving us a snippet, please provide a short but complete program which does *nothing* but demonstrate the problem. We can't tell what's wrong here - it doesn't help that you haven't told us what you've observed as the values of `searchID` in either case.

Comment: I received a link to "asking a proper question" in the past because it was "too long", so I was afraid of getting trolled with downvotes. I will edit it to include everything.

Comment: I think the code you provided is probably enough to diagnose the problem, but we need to know what you entered as input, as that seems to be the most like cause of problems cause of problems. Additionally, remember that the `equals(searchID)` check is case sensitive (unless you specify that it should be, which you're not doing).

Comment: I added .equalsIgnoreCase(searchID) after I read this. Thanks for the reminder. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program "eats" your new line. That will cause the program to to skip one line.

If you type: 
input.nextLine();
input.nextLine();  (twice that is)

it should work

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)